# How do i write an algorithm that reads three numbers and prints them out in ascending order in python

Tags: python, if-statement, iif-function

How do i write an algorithm that reads three numbers and prints them out in ascending order in python. Please help this is what i have tried so far i hope you guys can help me out thank you, this is using python and i am new to programming. I do not know how to do the part where it says in ascend orders.

```
one = float(input("Please input a number : "))
two = float(input("Please input a second number : "))
three = float(input("Please input a third number : "))

if one > two and three:
    print("")*
```

Comment: `sorted([one, two, three])`

Comment: Numbers are said to be in ascending order when they are arranged from the smallest to the largest number. E.g. 5, 9, 13, 17 and 21 are arranged in ascending order. [from www.mathsteacher.com.au](http://www.mathsteacher.com.au/year7/ch02_power/06_asc/asc.htm)
If you are in a 101 Programming Course, I think the problem is related to conditionals. You should check the `if...else`  statement. [Check this page](http://www.openbookproject.net/books/bpp4awd/ch04.html)

Comment: @idjaw can you explain how to do it? I dont understand it

Comment: @JoseRaulBarreras I know what it means but i dont know how to do it in python

Comment: you mean `if one > two > three:`.Drop the `and` !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use sorted(), but first you have a save the numbers in a list, try with this:

```
nums = []
one = nums.append(float(input("Please input a number : ")))
two = nums.append(float(input("Please input a second number : ")))
three = nums.append(float(input("Please input a third number : ")))
for num in sorted(nums):
    print (num)
```

[sorted() - Python Doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)

If you need use a if and else statement, you should think in all combinations about your input numbers and evaluate this, try with this:

```
one = float(input("Please input a number : "))
two = float(input("Please input a second number : "))
three = float(input("Please input a third number : "))

if one < two and three < two:
    if one > three:
        print(three, one, two)
    else:
        print(one, three, two)
elif one < three and two < three:
    if one > two:
        print(two, one, three)
    else:
        print(one, two, three)        
elif two < one and three < one:
    if three > two:
        print(two, three, one)
    else:
        print(three, two, one)
else:
    print(one, two, three)
```

Comment: Check the other solution that I posted, you can use the statements if and else

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, the following one, will print in order the numbers one and two in ascending order. I suggest you try to complete the code for three elements.

```
one = float(input("Please input a number : "))
two = float(input("Please input a second number : "))
three = float(input("Please input a third number : "))

if one < two:
    print(one, two)
else:
    print(two, one)
```

Your move...

Comment: how do i do it with three numbers?